# 2 Cisco ASA Firewalls - TCP SYN FLOOD

Tags: routing, network, cisco-asa, flood

**Problem**

We have 2 firewalls, a DMZ firewall and another firewall named FW1 in a testlab. Both are CISCO ASAs. The shared services and jumphost are behind the FW1 firewall. The 172.28.208.0/24 subnets are all behind the FW1 firewall. On the FW1 firewall, we have the routing 0.0.0.0/0 configured so that it points to the DMZ firewall interface. That way any external traffic goes first through the DMZ and then WAN Routers and out of the local network.

The problem is - when a host tries to talk to a server, let's say 172.28.208.9, and this IP does not exist for some reason, let's say someone mistakenly ssh into 172.28.208.9 instead of 172.28.208.10, then the packet is bouncing between these 2 firewalls creating a TCP SYN flood.

I've added threat-detection for TCP syn flood on the firewalls, but after a while even this mechanism is not containing the issue and CPU starts to rise drastically after tcp syn flood

**Next steps - attempting**

I am trying to 'enable unicast RPF routing globally', by using the commands "ip cef, multicast-routing, ip verify unicast source reachable-via rx'

It will be great if you can pelase advise whether that would fix the issue or what is the best practices to follow in this case?

Comment: You seem to have a routing problem - are you using some kind of proxy ARP? Or why is *when ... this IP does not exist* ever routed elsewhere when there's only a single subnet with that prefix?

Comment: Point-to-point links can be subject to ping-pong attacks, which is why you use `/31` or `/30` for IPv4 and `/127` for IPv6 on point-to-point links.

Comment: Your description is unclear. What subnets are on the inside interface of the FW1 firewall aside from 172.28.208.0/24? What subnet is on its outside interface? What subnets are on the DMZ firewall interfaces? You really should just show sanitized configuration of the firewalls otherwise everyone has to guess.